# Post process Enum.to_list

Tags: elixir

I have this pipeline

```
 events
 |> Task.async_stream(&expensive_func/1)
 |> Enum.to_list
```

Which returns this data:

```
[ok: {item}, ok: {item} ... ]
```

So, in order to just have an array of items, `[item, item]` I post processed it like this:

```
 events
 |> Task.async_stream(&expensive_func/1)
 |> Enum.to_list
 |> Enum.map(fn {:ok, event} -> event end)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to take into account here is: tasks might fail. If the desired behaviour is to just discard them, simply use the example directly from the [`Task.async_stream/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Task.html#async_stream/3-example) example and *explicitly discard them*:

```rb
events
|> Task.async_stream(&expensive_func/1)
|> Enum.reduce([], fn
  {:ok, event}, acc -> [event | acc]
  _, acc -> acc # discard failures
end)
|> Enum.reverse()
```

Another option would be to rely on the task’s return value (if it returns e. g. `nil` on failure,) then one might directly use [`Keyword.values/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Keyword.html#values/1):

```rb
events
|> Task.async_stream(&expensive_func/1)
|> Enum.to_list()
|> Keyword.values()
```

---

FWIW, your original solution would raise `MatchError` if there is at least one task failed because your function doesn’t handle `:error`s.

Comment: One question, why is the reverse needed? Enum.reduce is reversing it also?

Comment: Prepending items to the linked list `[event | acc]` is way faster than appending `acc ++ [event]`, that’s why the code above has been prepending them, which reverses the original input (LIFO.)

Comment: mm I think the reduce might slow it anyway, I am receiving:
** (exit) exited in: Task.Supervised.stream(5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out

Comment: I have never experienced that and it’s extremely unlikely that `Enum.reduce/3` would be slowing it down. If `Enum.to_list()` in the middle does the trick in your particular case, just embed it before `Enum.reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
events
|> Task.async_stream(&expensive_func/1))
|> Enum.map(&(elem(&1,1)))
```

**warning**: Since we directly access second element of the tuple returned by each `Task`, no check are made to ensure the `Task` has been correctly run. You can add a pattern matching on `:ok` to fix that issue (as you did in the question).

Comment: This will hide any task failures. just fyi.

Comment: @Botonomous it is due to the fact it does not pattern match on `:ok`,  or am I missing something ?

Comment: No it’s because you are hiding elem(0).

Comment: Ok @Botonomous , I think I choose a wrong wording. Thank you for your feed back, I have edited the answer to correct that.